# Is it possible to use Spring's @RequestBody in a Grails action?

Tags: java, json, grails, spring-mvc

I would like to use Spring's `@RequestBody` annotation to bind JSON from the request body to an object.  Is it possible to use this in a Grails controller method?  If not, is there a more elegant way other than using the `request.JSON` object which is created?

Here is what I'm trying to do:
**FooController.groovy:**

```
def someMethod(@RequestBody Bar bar) {
    render(bar.baz)
}

class Bar {
    String baz
}
```

I then POST the following JSON to this endpoint:

```
{
    "baz":"chicken"
}
```

I would expect the response from the POST to be `chicken`.

Any idea if this is possible, or is there some other mechanism to bind JSON to a controller argument like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `resource` or `parseRequest` in the relevant URL mapping (see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html for details) then the incoming JSON will be parsed and used to fill the `params` map, i.e. the JSON

```
{
    "baz":"chicken"
}
```

Will set `params.baz == "chicken"`. The resulting params entries can then be bound into a command object in the usual way, you shouldn't need to annotate the action parameter.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much Ian!!  I was really hoping that Grails would have something like this... I was going to be disappointed if it didn't.  Yet again, I find that I needed to RTFM :)

Comment: Amazing ! Is it possible to enable `parseRequest` for all controllers ? Because with this solution I had to declare all my controllers in urlMapping, just to enable this option.

Comment: Ok I've just have to add `parseRequest` on the generic url mapping `/$controller/$action?/$id?`. Is there some caveats to do so?

Comment: The main caveat is that with `parseRequest:true`, controller actions can no longer access the request data directly - if any of your controllers (or those in any plugins you use) require that then you'll need to add special cases for those.